# How can I make div 100% of window width meanwhile parent's width is 95.5%?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass

Ive got a small problem. I have react-dom-route's in my Navbar and the problem is that it gives me back the div with max width of its parent. The thing I want to do is using route from navbar to render View which has its own scss-properties.

A small sample of code:

```
return (
<Router>
.................
<div className="navbar_bottom-button">
<Link to="/foo" className="navbar-link">
    Foo
</Link>
</div>
.......
 <Switch>
<Route path="/foo">
<Foo />
</Route>
</Switch>
</Router>
```

Css of navbar's container:

```
.navbar_container {
position: absolute;
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
margin-left: 2%;
z-index: 4;
width: 95.5%;
text-shadow: 4px 4px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

Foo's css:

```
.foo-container {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 100%;
 min-width: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 left: 0px;
 background-color: purple;
 top: 1000px;
 height: 1000px;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 text-shadow: none;
 }
```

At this point it gets 100% of parent's width which is 95.5% instead of 100% width of window. How could I fix that?

Comment: width:100vw might be okay .

Comment: set it to 104.7% (100/95.5)

Comment: Thank you guys! Both of your answers were correct <3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `100vw` as the unit instead of `100%`

`vw` is Viewport Width so it will represent the windows width instead of your parents element.

If you're looking for height you could use `vh` for Viewport Height as well.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yeah thank all of you guys for answer, it really did help me! Now I have to get rid of that margin which is in navbar-container and is still present in foo's container after using margin: 0;

Comment: I'm not sure I understand where the margin is coming from, do you have a codepen that shows what you're seeing?

Comment: margin is comming from 'navbar-container' as the width does :( 
navbar-container has 2..5% of margin-left, I have to set '-2.06% ' of margin-left at foo-container to make it look "okay". Dont think -2.06% will be responsive tho..

Comment: I don't think you should have to go to that length. Without seeing the full code though or an example I'm not really seeing what could be causing that. I'd have to be able to dig into it and find out. It sounds like you want a basic app with a header and page content anyways, I've made a quick example in code pen to show you a generic outline of that: https://codepen.io/sean-mooney/pen/XWmeEpV
If this doesn't clear it up for you, could you create your own pen reproducing the issue?

Comment: Sure man, Ive just finished reproducing that. Thats how it looks like: https://codepen.io/Goteii/pen/rNOGdvv

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still not understanding what you're trying to achieve. I see the margin but I also see you have a `position: absolute` in side the element of another `position: absolute` which can be good/bad but depends on what you're trying to do, in this case I think it's bad though. - It seems like you're wanting the navbar to contain an entire page element, I don't think it has to work like that? Sorry for so much back and forth but I'm happy to help you fix this

Comment: Dont be sorry, Im happy that you try to help me! I still learn.. It would be better if i could show you how it looks like though.. Anyway: Navbar is absolute because its above the div of "mainPageView" and that "boosting_container" is absolute as well because it actually comes in instead of that "mainPageView" div

Comment: Right but I'm confused on what the boosting container actually does or where it should be on the page. From your example it looks like the boosting_container is the actual page's content based on the route? Pages normally just have a navbar and a page, the page is changed based on the current route. I'm not familiar with what it is or why a boosting container is needed. If you have discord or something I could take a better look at this, I'm just not following what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Sure man I do have Discord. Its Goteii#1134. I think I will be able to explain you that better there

Comment: Added you there

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`vw` units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length). An element set to `100vw` will always be 100% of the window, regardless of its parent's width.

You could also use percentages. An element that is `104.71204188%` the width of an element that is `95.5%` the width of the window, will be `100%` of the width of the window.